# what vba code for outlook email to choose between .send or .display with reference to a cell

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to send a outlook email using vba allowing user to choose between 
.send or
.display
With reference to a cell.

Anyway to do it?

Comment: Sure - if the cell value is "Send", then `.Send`. Or if the cell value is "Display", then `.Display`. Should be easy to translate that with `If`, or `Select Case`.

Answer (score 0):

An example of how to achieve this would be as below, assuming Column A contains the email address and Column B contains either "Display" or "Send":

```
Sub LoopThroughRows_SendEmail()
Dim OutApp As Object: Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim OutMail As Object: Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with

For i = 2 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
'loop from Row 2 To Last Row in UsedRange
    With OutMail
        .To = ws.Cells(i, "A").Value 'get email address from Column A
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Subject"
        .Body = "Please contact us to discuss blah blah blah......"

        If ws.Cells(i, "B").Value = "Display" Then
        'if column B contains "Display" then .Display, else .Send
          .Display
        ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "B").Value = "Send" Then
          .Send
        End If
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```